# Mostrar los datos del proyecto que tiene el máximo de horas

Tags: sql, oracle

Muy buenas gente, ¿alguien puede decirme qué hago mal? A mi parecer la consulta está correcta, pero el resultado es el erróneo. Me señala que en el HAVING, no puedo operar con la función MAX.

**Enunciado:** Mostrar los datos del proyecto que tiene el máximo de horas.

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT projectes.*
   FROM projectes
   GROUP BY projectes.codi_projecte, projectes.nom, projectes.hores, projectes.codi_especialitat;
   HAVING MAX (projectes.hores);
```

**Resultado obtenido:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado esperado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Relación de las tablas:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Contenido de las tablas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás usando oracle?

Comment: Sí, ¿por qué lo dices?

Comment: Porque siempre se debería agregar la etiqueta correspondiente a la pregunta. De todas formas, el `HAVING` recibe una condición lógica, es similar a un `WHERE`, pero que filtra después de haber hecho las agregaciones. En tu caso, no tienes ninguna condición

Comment: ¿Y cómo le digo que solo me muestre los datos del proyecto con más horas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías hacer algo así:

```sql
SELECT p.codi_projecte, p.nom, p.hores, p.codi_especialitat
FROM projectes p left join projectes pMax on p.Hores < pMax.Hores 
Where pMax.codi_projecte is NULL
```

Comment: Al final saqué la query, era una subconsulta.


`SELECT projectes.*
   FROM projectes
   WHERE projectes.hores = (SELECT MAX (projectes.hores) FROM projectes);`

Gracias por la ayuda, aunque nunca he usado operadores en el from.

Comment: Exacto, es mas performante el left join por eso lo codié de esa manera, me alegro que te haya servido! Saludos.